Solution of $\frac{1}{2 \pi^2} \int_m^\infty \frac{x \sqrt{x^2-m^2}}{e^{(x-\mu)/T} + 1}dx$
$m\geq 0$ and $T>0$. I'm currently stumped on this and only have the solution for $m=0$, which is
$$-\frac{T}{\pi^2}\text{Li}_3\left(e^{-\frac{\mu}{T}}\right)$$, where $\text{Li}_3(x)$ is the Trilogarithm. I substituted $x/T$ and then identified the new Integral as a complete Fermi-Dirac Integral, which has a direct relation to the Polylog. I am now in search of a general solution, but I can't seem to solve this. Also useful are the cases $\mu=0$ or $\mu=m$. Thanks in advance.$$\frac{1}{2 \pi^2} \int_m^\infty \frac{x \sqrt{x^2-m^2}}{e^{(x-\mu)/T} + 1}dx$$

Can you give a little more context?  Do you have some reasonable expectation that there is a general solution to this integral in terms of elementary functions?  Where did you encounter this problem?

@abiessu the OP mentioned that it is a Fermi-Dirac integral. The integral is the number of particles in a 3D relativistic gas of mass $m$, temperature $T$ and chemical potential $\mu$

You also know the $m\to\infty$ limit which gives you $\text{Li}_{3/2}$. Btw you can get rid of one of the three parameters $m,T,\mu$ by scaling

I know that there are solutions for $\mu\gg T$ and $\mu \ll T$, which are $\frac{1}{6\pi^2}\left(\mu^2-m^2\right)^{3/2}$ and $\frac{m^2}{2\pi^2}e^{\mu/T}K_2(\mu/T)$ respectively, where $K_2$ is a modified Bessel function. I arrived there by approximating the Fermi-Dirac part first as a step function and then as a Boltzmann dist. I dont know if a general solution exists, but i am curious

As to where this integral originates @LPZ was on point, its part of a thesis i work on regarding neutrino phase space distributions and this is the volume of a fermi gas at a temperature $T$ with neutrinos of mass $m$. The upper factor and the constant arise from the transition from momentum to energy and the Fermi Dirac part is the distribution of the Fermi gas
